# Different size columns with kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Good day everyone,
I'm having trouble with Kivy for python for I'm not able to change this code in order to get columns of different sizes.

```
    BoxLayout:
        RecycleView:
            viewclass: 'Button'
            data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.data_items]
            background_normal: ''
            RecycleGridLayout:
                cols: 5

                default_size: None, dp(35)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None

                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
                background_normal: ''
```

with this code I get 5 columns all of the same size.
But I want the first column to be larger then the other fours.
Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GridLayout's `cols_minimum` with `size_hint_x: None` or `size_hint: None, None`.

## Note

- There is no attribute, `background_normal` in RecycleView and RecycleGridLayout.
- There is no attribute, `orientation` in RecycleGridLayout.

## Snippet

```
BoxLayout:
    RecycleView:
        viewclass: 'Button'
        data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.data_items]

        RecycleGridLayout:
            cols: 5
            cols_minimum: {0: 300, 1: 100, 2: 200, 3: 100, 4: 150}
            size_hint: None, None
            default_size: None, dp(35)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.minimum_height
```

[GridLayout » cols_minimum](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html#kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout.cols_minimum)

> ```
> cols_minimum
> ```
>
> Dict of minimum width for each column. The dictionary keys are the
> column numbers, e.g. 0, 1, 2…
>
> cols_minimum is a [DictProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.DictProperty) and defaults to {}.